# Execute VBA to Change Reminder Time Based on Calendar

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

ALL events created in outlook 2007 have the same default reminder time. It seems you cannot change this time for individual calendars.

I have two calendars I use within outlook: my normal "events" calendar and a separate calendar I use to track task items I want to work on at specific times. I want them to have different reminder times (specifically for the tasks one, 0 minutes).

I would like to make a macro to execute every time an event is created to:

- check calendar name
- change reminder time for events belonging to 1 calendar (to 0 min)

Any resources would be appreciated. I've done significant VBA programming in Excel but documentation on Outlook vba (as well as a lack of "record macro" in outlook) makes it hard because it is really not intuitive for me.

I am trying something (kinda shooting in the dark based on lots of searching..) like this (as a class module)

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlItems = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)


Dim myCAlEntry As Outlook.MeetingItem

MsgBox ("test")


End Sub
```

I should clarify: I am unable to see "test" in a message box when creating calendar events right now.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this? http://blog.prossel.info/30-solution-to-disturbing-default-reminder-for-outlook-all-day-events/

Comment: yes, but that is for a part of the process I cannot get to yet - I am currently unable to have a method called each time a new event is created on the calendar (this seemingly should be easy?)

Answer (score 0):

In ThisOutlookSesion:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlItems = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
End Sub
```

You do not need Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
End Sub
```

The original setup should work with:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub
```